# MySQL: how to store height/weight information?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to capture user's height and weight in my database. In the UI, I need to provide an option to specify height in centimeters and inches -- and for weight, kilograms and pounds. Later on, when I display the users, I need to display their height and weight in only 1 unit of measurement (e.g. either in cms or ins for all of them).

What's the best way to store this data? Do I store 2 pieces of data for height (e.g. height value, height unit) and 2 pieces of data for weight (e.g. weight value, weight unit), then store user's data as inputted? When I need to display the data in uniform units, then I do conversion in the SQL.

Or should I convert the data before being stored that way I don't need to do conversation later when I need to display the user data?

By the way, when I display the data back to the actual user, it has to be in the same units the user picked.

Comment: Which is more important? 1. Be able to play back exactly what the user typed in? or 2. Be able to easily compare the heights and weights in the db? or 3. Be able to display all data to any user in units she prefers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think normalization - unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise, store it in one place, in one format, and always use the standard conversion in your code later on.  The database should store your data, not the business rules.

Comment: 180 cm and 72 inches are both data. I don't see this as a business rule. Doing the conversion before the inserts means that I might not be able to accurately convert it back to the user later on.

Comment: Yes, they're both data, but they're not the same - you're asking your database to know the rules of converting them for your business.  If you're accurately storing it, then there's no reason that you'd be unable to convert it to the user's preference later on - THOSE are the business rules.

Answer (score 0):

You definitly want to save only one height and only one width - use a unit of your choice. Unit conversion is a single multiplication, which is in essence a zero cost.

You can also have a units table, and a simple inner join with a calculated field will give you the correct numerical value in a single query (SELECT as well as INSERT/UPDATE)

Comment: So, say I choose metric system. Save all heights in cms; save all weights in kgs. Later, the person who saved his height in inches -- I'll have to convert back from cms, which may not be accurate for him anymore. Is that really what I should do?

Comment: Yes, it should: A single precision float with a single division and a single multiplication applied will give you much better precision as any weight or height needs! You simply don't care, if the weight is wrong by some milligrams.

Comment: What's the disadvantage of me saving exactly how the user inputted the data -- then doing the conversion when I need to display all the users using the same unit of measurement?

Comment: The disadvantage is inconsistent data - you'll always need to do an additional check on those columns in each row to know what the data actually is.

Comment: 1. You double the storage requirement, 2. you run into big problems, if the fields get out of sync, 3. you have difficulties comparing, 4. its not normailzed, 5. You need a table and business logic overhaul if you wanto use more than 2 fields (i.e. inches, cm and a third unit)

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing the normalization problem. How is it not normalized if I store: (180, cms), (72, ins)?

Comment: Simple: 72 inches is **more** than 180 cms, but 72 is **less** than 180 - so you lose comparability of a numerical value. This contradicts normalization, via loss of field independence.

Comment: I didn't mean those to be the converted values. Say user 1 is 72 inches. User 2 is 180 cms.

Comment: Exactly. So there is a numerical field, one has 72, the other has 180, but 72>180